# How to properly do a Java sql query with multiple boolean functions

Tags: java, mysql, function

I want every boolean to be true so the last "insertSale()" function can be used. I tried with private int "provera". When a boolean is true the "provera" adds 1 into its value so provera needs to have a value of 4 if I want to use InsertSale() function. But the problem is when I start the application and insert values that exist in the database the value of "provera" is still 0. How should I do this?

First I check if customer exists in the database.

```
private boolean customerExists() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    try (java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/webshop", "root", "traktor123");) {

        if (customer != null && !(customer.isEmpty())) {
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            st.executeQuery("select name from customer where (name='" + customer + "')");
        }
        provera = provera+1;
        return true;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in database: \n" + ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then I check if the product exists.

```
private boolean productExists() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    try (java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/webshop", "root", "traktor123");) {

        if (product != null && !(product.isEmpty())) {
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            st.executeQuery("select productName from product where (productName = '" + product + "')");
        }
        provera = provera+1;
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in database: \n" + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Produkt ne postoji");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I need to find a quantity of products. If both customer and product exist, this function needs to be used.

```
public boolean findQuantity() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    if (customerExists() == true && productExists() == true) {
        try (java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/webshop", "root", "traktor123");) {
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            st.executeQuery("select quantity from product where (productName='" + product + "')");
            ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
            while (rs.next()) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("quantity")) != 0) {
                    finalQuantity = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("quantity"));
                } 
            }
            provera = provera+1;
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in database: \n" + ex.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    } 
    return false;

}
```

When I find the value of quantity left I want to have less when a customer buys it.

```
private boolean lessQuantity() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    if (findQuantity() == true) {
        try (java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/webshop", "root", "traktor123");) {
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            st.execute("update webshop.product set quantity = '" + (finalQuantity - 1) + "' where productName = '" + product + "'");
            provera = provera+1;
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in database: \n" + ex.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code needs to be used only if all of the functions are true.

```
public void insertSale() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    System.out.println(provera);
    if(provera == 4){
        try (java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/webshop", "root", "traktor123");) {
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            st.execute("insert into sale (customer, product) values ('" + customer + "','" + product + "')");
            lessQuantity();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in database: \n" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you call the 4 methods that increment `provera` at all?

Comment: This question does not contain a [mcve]

Comment: @Sweeper I did try but still doesn't work

Comment: Are you writing your own ORM here? There's already dozens of those to pick from.

Comment: @tadman Yes, I had a tutorial that I followed. That's why I did it this way.

Comment: @tadman Can you help me?

Comment: You've dug yourself quite a hole by following that tutorial. There's some alarming [**SQL injection holes**](https://bobby-tables.com) in this code. If this is intended for production use, I'd abandon this code and use a well-tested ORM. This code can't be trusted, it can only be used for learning. There's a lot of high-quality ORMs in Java to pick from, but the important thing is you use one that exists and not use one that you've just cooked up without proper testing and community review.

Comment: @tadman This code is just for learning. How should I rewrite this code so the insertSale() can work fine?

Comment: For one, use placeholder values. The request requires testing, and for that I'd recommend adding unit tests to ensure the other parts leading up to that are working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The way that worked:

```
private boolean customerExists() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        try (java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/webshop", "root", "traktor123");) {
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            if (customer != null && !(customer.isEmpty())) {
                st.executeQuery("select name from customer where (name='" + customer + "')");
            }
            ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
            if (rs.next()) {
                return true;
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in database: \n" + ex.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println("Customer doesn't exist");
        return false;
    }

    private boolean productExists() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        try (java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/webshop", "root", "traktor123");) {
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            if (product != null && !(product.isEmpty())) {
                st.executeQuery("select productName from product where (productName = '" + product + "')");
            }
            ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
            if (rs.next()) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in database: \n" + ex.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println("Product doesn't exist");
        return false;
    }

    public boolean findQuantity() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        if (customerExists() == true && productExists() == true) {
            try (java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/webshop", "root", "traktor123");) {
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                st.executeQuery("select quantity from product where (productName='" + product + "')");
                ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("quantity")) != 0) {
                        finalQuantity = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("quantity"));
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Product quantity is 0");
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error in database: \n" + ex.getMessage());
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

    private boolean lessQuantity() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        if (findQuantity() == true) {
            try (java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/webshop", "root", "traktor123");) {
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                st.execute("update webshop.product set quantity = '" + (finalQuantity - 1) + "' where productName = '" + product + "'");
                return true;
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error in database: \n" + ex.getMessage());
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void insertSale() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        if (lessQuantity() == true) {
            try (java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/webshop", "root", "traktor123");) {
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                st.execute("insert into sale (customer, product) values ('" + customer + "','" + product + "')");
                System.out.println("Successfully bought");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error in database: \n" + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```